# Is a started via terminal script program halted when screen locks?

Tags: scripts, lock-screen, terminator

I would like to ask pretty much what the title says but I should better explain in details my situation.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed Protege.
I am trying to perform a task(export a new ontology) but it is taking too long. Before posting here, I have already checked a couple of things related to the program itself, the size of the files and my computer specs. Since the conclusion is that it is taking way above expected, I am looking for other reasons that can cause such a delay.

So, I am running Protege via a script from my terminal (not the default but Terminator, I don't know if that could make any difference). While searching I saw some posts about terminal scripts not running while the screen is locked. Do you think that this could be my case as well? Since Protege is "bound" to a terminal window, when the screen locks, the script halts, the program halts and the exporting stops.

Thank you in advance.